# How to get MS Teams' channel files and folders

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on an API and i want to get Files and Folders of a specific teams' channel. I've tried with Graph Explorer but could not find anything resource. I have also tried the official documentation [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/).

I have tried the following API in explorer but it does not give the desired results.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/filesFolder](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7BteamId%7D/channels/%7BchannelId%7D/filesFolder)

It is highly possible that i might have overlooked the my required resource but can someone help me out in it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the correct endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/filesFolder
```

returns metadata about [driveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Use `parentReference.driveId` and `id` in the next API call to get folders and files

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{id}/children
```

It returns a collection of `driveItems` with unique `id`.

- If `driveItem` represents a file then `file` property is not null.

For each item that represents the file you can call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}
```

to get more details about the file.

- If `driveItem` represents a folder then `folder` property is not null.

For each item that represents the folder you can call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}/children
```

to get more details about the folder or to get items inside the folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was able to achieve my results.